# Object in ViewModel Null on Post MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewmodel

I've looked pretty hard for an answer on this and I can't tell exactly what I'm doing wrong.

I have a partial view with its own Model

```
@model ViewModels.NotificationPartialViewModel
@if (Model.CurrentNotification != null)
{
    <input name="CurrentNotification" id="CurrentNotification" type="hidden" value="@Model.CurrentNotification"/>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentNotification.NotificationType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentNotification.NotificationStart)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentNotification.NotificationEnd)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TimeZoneOffset, new { @class = "timeZoneOffset" })
    if (Model.CurrentNotification.NotificationType == Model.DowntimeKey)
    {
    <div class="fieldList">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>@Resources.PageLabels.Legend_NotificationDowntime</legend>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label(Resources.PageLabels.Label_StartNotification)</div>
                <div class="editor-field newline-wrapper wide">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NotificationStartDateTime)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NotificationStartDateTime)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field device">
                    <input type="date" id="NotificationStartDateTime_DevicePicker" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                <div class="editor-label">@Html.Label(Resources.PageLabels.Label_EndNotification)</div>
                <div class="editor-field newline-wrapper wide">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NotificationEndDateTime)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NotificationEndDateTime)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field device">
                    <input type="date" id="NotificationEndDateTime_DevicePicker" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    }
    else if (Model.CurrentNotification.NotificationType == Model.HotfixKey)
    {       
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="DisplayHotfixNotification">@Resources.PageLabels.Label_DisplayHotfix</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DisplayHotfixNotification)</div>
    </div>
    }
}
```

I'm refreshing the view with a drop down list via an ajax call on the view that holds the partial:

```
function reloadNotificationPartial() {
    var notificationID = document.getElementById("SelectedNotification").value;

$.ajax(
{
    url: '@Url.Action("ReloadNotifications")?notificationID=' + notificationID,
    success: function (html) {
        //Refresh the notification list.
        $('#MainPanel').html(html);
    }
});
```

}

And here is the controller action:

```
public PartialViewResult ReloadNotifications(Guid? notificationID)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        NotificationPartialViewModel vm = new NotificationPartialViewModel();

        _notificationRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<INotificationRepository>();
        List<Notification> noteList = _notificationRepository.GetAllNotifications();

        vm.CurrentNotification = noteList.SingleOrDefault(n => n.NotificationType.Equals(notificationID));

        vm.CurrentNotification.NotificationStart = ConvertToBrowserTime(vm.CurrentNotification.NotificationStart,
                                                                         SecurityCookieManager.getTimeZoneOffset(
                                                                             this.HttpContext));

        vm.CurrentNotification.NotificationEnd = ConvertToBrowserTime(vm.CurrentNotification.NotificationEnd,
                                                                       SecurityCookieManager.getTimeZoneOffset(
                                                                           this.HttpContext));
        //Ajax Request, only return the partial view
        return PartialView("NotificationPartial", vm);
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException("Action is not supported in the manner it was called.");
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is save one of two types of notifications based on a drop down list. When I save back the information CurrentNotification is always null and I haven't been able to figure out what I'm missing to fix this issue, if you need anything else let me know. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the controller action to see if the `CurrentNotification` property is being set to something useful?  The Linq `SingleOrDefault` method may return `null` which should cause other issues.  Set a break on the `return` statement and see what is actually being passed in, then set a break on the `if` statement in the partial view and see what you're getting as a model.

Comment: Had a similar issue once but turned out I had just forgotten to add getters and setters to the properties in my view model

Comment: after save you are reloading the notifications?

Comment: @Corey - Yes I've made sure that its not null on the reload with the singleordefault, its even being set properly in the f12 console window, the hiddenfor has the proper values I believe

Comment: @AltafSami - No I'm reloading it before I save. Essentially its just  reload and replace of a partial view.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that it was a two fold issue, one I was not creating a new CurrentNotification in the view model constructor, and then after I put that in I was over writing my new CurrentNotification that I just created with a hidden one replacing the good object with the null one.